# How can I calculate score using More-like-this in script score in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm writing a query for searching engine.
I want to calculate the score using cosine similarity(between **image feature vectors**) and **TFIDF**.
So, I used "function_score" to calculate weighted sum of more-like-this score and cosine similarity.
I found that I should use "script_score" inside "functions" when I use function_score.
But I didn't work. Can anybody help me? Thanks.

This is my query.

```
script_query = {
"function_score": {
  "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {"match": {"unitCode": unitCode}},
                        {"match": {"problemLevel": problemLevel}}

                    ]
                }
            },
 
  "functions": [
    {
        "script_score": {
                "script": {
                    "source": "cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, 'fvec') + 1.0",
                    "params": {"query_vector": fvec}
                }
        }
    
    },
    {
        "script_score": {
          "script": { 
                      "source":
                         {"more_like_this" : 
                              {
                                "fields" : ["plainText"],
                                "like" : text,
                                "min_term_freq" : 0,
                                "min_doc_freq" : 0,
                                "minimum_should_match" : "0%"
                                }
                            }
                    }
            }
    }         
  ],
  "score_mode": "sum",
  "boost_mode": "sum",
  "max_boost": 4,
  "min_score": 3
}
```